# How to get the namespace alias operator :: to work under C#?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, alias

I've come up against the unlikely scenario when I reference two external assemblies that both have the same namespace and type names. When I try to use the type, the compiler throws an error that it cannot resolve which one I want to use.

I see that C# offers a mechanism to use aliases for references. You can even specify these aliases via the `Property` window of a reference in Visual Studio 2008. How do I use this alias in my code? As I understand, I should be using the `::` operator, but it fails with the following error:

> `CS0432 - Alias not found`

The usual `.` operator fails as well.

In the output window I see that the compiler gets the alias passed correctly in its command line.

Any pointers on what I may be able to try next are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The usual . operator fails as well." can you expand on this one? It DOES work if you type the whole namespace

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
extern alias alias1;
using alias1::Namespace;
```

Comment: This can be used for a method to workaround around CS0433 ( C# compiler error ). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64wh5743(VS.100).aspx

Comment: I just noticed, it's 1 error number from "Gortok's" question here, funny.

Comment: And, you also need to change the assembly-reference property 'Aliases' from "global" to "global, alias1".

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
extern alias asm1;
extern alias asm2;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            asm1.MyNs.MyClass mc1 = null;
            asm2.MyNs.MyClass mc2 = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And add `global,asm1` to the project reference for assembly1 and `global,asm2` for assembly2

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use an  **extern alias**. [Anson Horton](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) has a good blog on this problem and how to use **extern alias** to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

When you reference some assembly in project it has default alias "global". When you add another alias for that assembly, e.g. "global, AssemblyA", you will reference it like this:

```
using SomeTypeAlias = AssemblyA::Company.Product.SomeType;
```

or:

```
void SomeMethod(AssemblyA::Company.Product.SomeType someType) { ... }
```