# Namespace conflict in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

There is a `System` namespace inside my program's namespace. And as a result I can't see the standard `System` namespace from within mine. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

For example in C++ there is the `::` operator which 'shifts' me out of my namespace, so I can see external namespaces with the same name as my current namespace:

[image]

Is there a similar operator in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the namespace alias operator :: to work under C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619104/how-to-get-the-namespace-alias-operator-to-work-under-c)

Comment: Why not just use better names other than `System`?

Comment: Sorry to derail, but if those screen shots are from Visual Studio, what color theme are you using?

Comment: @0A0D: I made it just for example :) I just want to know answer for this question

Comment: @Roberto Sebestyen: Its not color theme of VS, I had changed standard white window's color in system appearence, so all programms which uses `SystemColors.Window` color have same gray color. It very good for eyes

Comment: Also, same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914742/c-problem-trying-to-resolve-a-class-when-two-namespaces-are-similar

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You need to use the `global` keyword. That forces the namespace resolution to start at the very top. It's mostly used in generated code to be doubly sure the right namespace is referenced.

```
 global::System.Foo.Bar;
```

Some MSDN documentation on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: As an aside, it's probably best to avoid using `System` as a name of namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately some code generators don't add the "global::" keyword. :-( Like the one WPF uses.

Comment: @MattGreer I agree, but keep in mind you can also conflict with third party libraries' root namespaces.

Comment: Handy MSDN Link that.

Answer (score 20):

For more convenience, you can give it an alias, too:

```
using GSystem = global::System;
```

Will allow you to refer to the global `System` namespace as `GSystem` or whatever else you would like to call it.

Answer (score 4):

yes

```
global::System
```

Strange though that you are getting a conflict with system.

Nothing should declare that namespace except system itself....

Comment: He declared `NamespaceConflict.System` in his own code for the purpose of demonstration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx)