# Fixing namespace collision issue in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

My application has the following namespace formatting:

- Company.Division.MyApplication.MyOtherStuff

I am being asked to use a library that has the following namespace formatting:

- Division.TheirApplication.TheirOtherStuff

However, a namespace collision is occurring at *Division* & I cannot resolve anything in *TheirApplication*.

The using statements wont resolve.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is collision?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681537/namespace-conflict-in-c-sharp

Comment: Did you try namespace alias like this - `using MyOtherStuff = global::Company.Division.MyApplication.MyOtherStuff` and `using TheirOtherStuff = global::Division.TheirApplication.TheirOtherStuff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `global` alias:

```
global::Division.TheirApplication.TheirOtherStuff
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx