# How do I resolve a namespace conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I ran into a strange problem with namespaces in a project of mine while creating test classes.

So I have a nuget package that I made and its namespace is

`ppumkin.APIService`

Then I created another solution for tests and the namespace on that solution is

`tests.ppumkin.ControllersAPI`

Problem is that I am trying to access my nuget packages dll object but visual studio is telling me that, `that` object does NOT exist in `tests.APIService` but the code I wrote is

`var obj = new ppumkin.APIService.TheClass()`

How to I tell Visual Studio that the object is NOT in `tests.ppumkin.APIService` but just in `ppumkin.APIService` *(eg - without the prefixed test namespace)*

I can overcome this problem if I use the same object creation outside of all namespaces define in the test project.

Comment: The best way is to name your tests *project* `tests.ppumpkin`, and set its *default namespace* to be `ppumpkin`. Then when you create a test file, it will already be in the same namespace as your target project. Of course, this means you should change the namespace of all of the files in the test project to match `ppumpkin`. It saves you from having to make a `using` statement in every file just to include a namespace which by definition you already need in your test.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you said there? and `ppumkin` is deliberate spelling :D I think my namespace needs to be changed so the test is on the end and not the start

Comment: What I am saying is, put all of your tests in the *exact same namespace* as your classes under test (regardless of what it is). Namespaces can span multiple assemblies. Then you save yourself from importing the namespace in every file (since your tests will already be in that namespace).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace conflict in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681537/namespace-conflict-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can solve your problem, create an alias for your using pointing at the namespace of your service. Alias can be then used to reference the correct namespace that contains the class that you are trying to create and instance of.

```
using apiservice = ppumkin.APIService;

namespace tests.ppumkin.ControllersAPI
{
    class TestClass1
    {
        void test()
        {
            var obj = new apiservice.YourClass();
        }
    }
}

namespace ppumkin.APIService
{
    class YourClass
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a better solution to what I proposed. Here's the msdn link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You should also consider changing the namespace of your tests to ppumkin.APIService.tests, this would solve your namespacing problem completely

Comment: Yea it dawned on me while driving that I should really move the `tests` to the end .. as that is more inline with convention any way. Thanks for the answer J. Tuc... I forgot that you could to that but I think its just my namespaces need to be changed in this case!

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`global::`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) to indicate that you're using a namespace name that starts from the global root, not some contained namespace:

```
var obj = new global::ppumkin.APIService.TheClass()
```

Although I agree that renaming your namespaces is probably a wiser long-term move.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I realised that my namespace for the test project is incorrect.

Following convention of top level domain of `ppumkin.` by prefixing it with `test` I am changing the entire namespace encapsulation.

The correct thing to do in my case - because I can control the namespaces and I want them to be as correct as possible is to fix the namespace of the test project to

```
ppumkin.Tests.
ppumkin.APIService.
ppumkin.Domain.Models.
ppumkin.Domain.Interfaces.
```

Now everything works as it supposed to - It was just a blind naming issue