# Conflict between Azure and Microsoft.Azure namespaces

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I needed to add a new reference to my code, so I added `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` via the nuget package manager. That installation went through successfully, and I can see that in the references for my package.

However, when I attempt to add using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` to a given file, it cannot find it, from what I can tell because there are other references to `Microsoft.Azure.X`, and the Azure namespace is routed to the `Microsoft.Azure` namespace.

I was able to temporarily escape that issue by adding the reference outside of the namespace in the following way:

```
#pragma warning disable SA1200 // Using directives must be placed correctly
//using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
#pragma warning restore SA1200 // Using directives must be placed correctly

namespace X.Y.Z
{
    using System;
    ...
    using Microsoft.Azure.ResourceProvider.Common.Exceptions;
    ...
```

However, this is somewhat of a pain because I then have to add this to many classes and also it is preventing me from doing things like using the fully qualified object name for `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage` to not conflict with another class that is already named `ServiceBusMessage` within my solution.

Is there something I can do to have `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` be treated like any other import and not have it conflict with existing references?

Comment: Disabling warnings doesn't mean the problem goes away. You still risk using the wrong class. To fix this, only import one of the namespaces (eg `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.SomeTypeA`), and either use the full type name for classes in the other namespace, or use a `using` alias, eg `using ServiceTypeA=Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.SomeTypeA`. Both Visual Studio and Rider refactorings offer these choices when type names conflict.

Comment: Another option is to use two or more files to separate the classes/methods that need access to each namespace. Resource Manager and Service Bus are very different services and won't be used together most of the time. This means they shouldn't be referenced from the same class either. This warning is a sign that the class is trying to do multiple things at the same time

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I could refactor out the code to make the classes do only one thing, but it is not really feasible in this case since there is a large repo for my team that I wouldn't want to make so many changes to at this time. The aliasing of the import does help reduce the pain though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace conflict in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681537/namespace-conflict-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

- `Using` statements are to help **readability**, not really for performance.

Suppose the kind of using directive in the Headers section (`using` statements section), is to bring a namespace into scope where as the fully qualified namespace (Eg: `System.Text.StringBuilder`) - this kind of statement is for correctly using (creating and disposing) an object implementing the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.

- The `<fully-qualifed-type-name>` is the name of the type whose static members and nested types can be referenced without specifying a type name. If you don't provide a fully qualified type name, C# generates compiler error CS0246 as referenced from this [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

And As Panagiotis Kanavos suggested that, another option is to use two or more files to separate the classes/methods which needs access to each namespace.

Glad Nimish Todi, that you are trying to,

- Resolve the issue by refactoring out the code to make the classes do only their own functionalities instead of making changes many at this time where aliasing of the import does helps to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by importing the namespace using the 'global' keyword as shown below:

```
namespace X.Y.Z
{
    using System;
    ...
    using Microsoft.Azure.ResourceProvider.Common.Exceptions;    
    using global::Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
    ...
```

Whenever you use the '`using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`' statement inside the namespace block, the compiler tries to find whether there is any matching namespace sequence in the following order:

```
 1. X.Y.Z.Azure
 2. X.Y.Azure
 3. X.Azure
 4. Azure
```

If it finds a matching namespace among any of the above, it stops processing any further.

In your case, the compiler has found a match among the scenarios 1, 2 or 3 mentioned above. Let's say the match it has found is `X.Azure`. After this, it will try to search for `X.Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` instead of `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` - which it fails to find.

Using the global keyword, as shown above, tells the compiler to directly consider the namespace `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` and not attempt the sequence matching mentioned above.