# Aliased const hiding global const

Tags: c#

**Background**

The solution is an MVC web application, it connects to two versions of the the same API. The connectors are class libraries in which the respective version of the API's wsdl was consumed into a proxy class. The web project references both libraries (with the same namespace). The older, lesser used version is aliased, the newer version uses the global alias in an attempt to reduce the amout of alias qualifiers around the code base.

**The Issue**

When attempting to access a constant string in the newer global reference, I receive the value of the older aliased library.

```
  //New v6
  public class AgeCode
  {
    public const string Adult = "ADT";
    public const string Child = "CHD";
    public const string Infant = "INF";
  }

  //Old v5
  public class AgeCode
  {
    public const string Adult = "ADT";
    public const string Child = "CLD";
    public const string Infant = "INF";
  }

  //Output of the below is "CLD"
  var code = global::Gateways.API.AgeCode.Child
```

The situation is similar to this example:
http://www.davidarno.org/c-howtos/aliases-overcoming-name-conflicts-part-2-extern-alias/

However in my case both classes would have the variable 'Pi'.

**:EDIT:**

I have tried changing the const declerations to 'static readonly' with no success.

As requested (In all cases I've changed the API's name to 'API'):

```
<Reference Include="Gateways.API.5, Version=5.0.30922, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=111111111, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Libs\Gateways.API\5\Gateways.API.dll</HintPath>
  <Aliases>ApiV5</Aliases>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Gateways.API.6, Version=6.0.31238, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=222222222, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Libs\Gateways.API\6\Gateways.API.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman The aliased class is not 'used' in the class in which my issue occurs (There is no 'external alias ...' ), the other is "using Gateways.API".

Comment: @WillDud are both of these classes in the same namespace or in different namespaces?

Comment: @meh-uk They are both in the same namespace. We developed the library against version 5 of the API, then they released version 6, we updated that same code base (in a branch). Because we interfaced everything out, it was fairly easy to reference both versions in the same web project. The hardest part was 2 files with the same name in the \bin (and this bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution was related to something I omitted in the description.

There are 3 projects in the solution:

- Api connector library
- Business logic library
- Web site

I was updating the constants in the api connector library and copying the dlls directly to the web site, however it seems that I needed to recompile the business logic library with the new connector library dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that Visual Studio/MSBuild uses the first referenced value which matches the class pattern, so this means you're picking up the first referenced library (i.e. version 5 of the library).

I think if you add an alias of `ApiV6` to the new library like you've added a similar alias to the old library and use the using `using ApiV6::Gateways.API.AgeCode` to use the new libraries copy of `AgeCode`.

Comment: You might well find that a tool like [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) helps you with this sort of issue :).

Comment: Sorry it took so long to test your suggestion. I tried this, added ', ApiV6' to the alias field in the reference's properties. Then added 'extern alias ApiV6' to the top of the file in question then updated the using to 'using ApiV6::Gateways.API'.  Now when I run the application in debug, I can hover over the the 'AgeCode' object and it has the correct members (including 'CHD'), but when I advance the execution past the assignment the variable, the variable gets set to 'CLD'. I'm starting to think that this is a unique case that its not come up before and is bugged.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619104/how-to-get-the-namespace-alias-operator-to-work-under-c) help?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I've already got everything compiling. The issues is that at run-time, the wrong value is used (despite the debug info displaying correctly).

Comment: Check the source code out to a new directory and rebuild to make sure there are no artifacts remaining?

Comment: This was a good idea and lead me to my solution. So I will awarded you the bounty (when the minimum time is up). The actual solution was related to an omission in the description. There are 3 projects in the solution, the connector library, a business logic library that depends on the connector and the web site that depends on the business logic library. I was updating the constants in the connector library and copying the dlls to the site but it seems that I needed to recompile the business logic library with the new connector library dlls.